# MySQL Hex to Signed Char

Tags: mysql

How to convert 0xFF to -1?

What I've already tried

```
CONV(0xFF, 16, -10)
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the `0x` part.

Comment: This is the original code, from where it comes from.        CONV(HEX(REVERSE(SUBSTR(a.data, 1, 1))), 16, 10). How to remove 0x part in this case?

Comment: 1st you have converted to hex..you can keep it as string since conv will accept string also. Can you try `conv(reverse(substr(a.data,1,1))),16,10)`

Comment: What is the value of `a.data` ?

Comment: The value of a.data is 0xFF. And the expected output is -1. Which function will return -1 given 0xFF?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to use the conv function to convert from hex to decimal, then subtract the result from 256?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conv function to convert from hex to decimal, then subtract the result from 256